# Just allow 2 decimal places in input field - VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want that user just be allowed up to two decimal places on keypress input.
Already tried step="0.01", pattern="^\d*(.\d{0,2})?$" and toFixed(2), but for sure i did it wrong. Can you help me on this?

```
<input
   :value="preview && prop === 'amount'? formatAmount(value) : value"
   :name="prop + rowIndex"
   :input-type="(prop === 'amount' && preview) ? 'text' : rulesMeta[prop].type"
   :preview="preview"
   :disabled="!actions[rowIndex].active"
   @input="setRuleItem({ newValue: $event, prop, rowIndex, name: 'actions' })"
/>

--------------------------------------

formatAmount (value) {
      if (value === null) {
        return value
      }
      return formatCurrency(value).replace('€', '')
    }
    enter code here

-----------------
export const formatCurrency = (value, currency = 'EUR') => {
return `€${Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency, maximumFractionDigits: 20 }).format(value).replace('€', '')}`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this method in my project to format the value on input. The key is using `.toFixed(2)` to force 2 decimal places:

```
formatFixedDecimal(value) {
    const numValue = typeof value === "string" ? parseFloat(value) : value; // Ensure Number
    return numValue.toFixed(2); // Two decimal places
}
```